# Custom favicon in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am working with the Yii2 basic template. In layouts/main.php, in the head section, I have set

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->getHomeUrl(); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

or

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

or ... (so on), but anything seems to work. My application keeps on showing the basic template favicon instead of mine, that is in the root web folder as usual.

I know I could publish this file to avoid this problem, but I think there should be no need.

What am I doing wrong? And how does Yii2 displays its standard favicon anyway?

Comment: favicon may be cached by brower. Try to clear browser cache

Comment: Try open your site on private mode. On firefox is shortcut `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`. Check if it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as **rkm** mentioned it's because of browser cache. Easy fix is to add version like `../favicon.ico?v=1` and browser will load new version.

Comment: After a deep deep deep cache clearing and many other usual suspects (I was just about to format the PC, the server, ... ;) my custom favicon displays successfuly. I promise never will change it again. Thank you @scaisEdge and rkm

Comment: I think the proper way to do it is by using `registerLinkTag` answered by @johnsnails.

Comment: @johnsnails My answer doesn't exclude registerLinkTag

Answer (score 12):

Another way to set the favicon as described in the [documentaion](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerLinkTag()-detail) is by adding something like this to the `main.php` file located under `views/layouts`.
`$this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/png', 'href' => '/favicon.png']);`

Comment: Although I rather use `Url::to()` or `Url::toRoute()` as I just spent hour figuring out why it is not showing up (I have my app in directory and it wasnt prepending base Path...)

   `$this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/png', 'href' => Url::to(['/favicon.png'])]);`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this as simple as adding an extra line to your `AppAsset.php` file:

```
public $css = [
        [
            'href' => 'path-to-your-icon/icon-32x32.png',
            'rel' => 'icon',
            'sizes' => '32x32',
        ],
        [
            'href' => 'path-to-your-icon/icon-192x192.png',
            'rel' => 'icon',
            'sizes' => '192x192',
        ],
        [
            'href' => 'path-to-your-icon/icon-180x180.png',
            'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        ],
        'css/site.css',        
    ];
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: Thanks @Serghei Leonenco, this is the best solution !

Answer (score 2):

I have the favicon.ico in  app/web  directory and the code below is working properly

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: This code turns into ´<link type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">´ and the displayed favicon is still the Yii2 basic template one.

Comment: @Jorgeska for me turn in  `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/DigitalFenX/area_web_dev/catone2.0.0-dev/backend/web/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`. Waht kind of urlManager you have setting?

Comment: In Yii2 UrlManager seems to be configured as an application component in [[\yii\base\Application]] by default. In config/web.php I have got:      `'urlManager' => [ // PRODUCTION-J
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // Disable r= routes
                'rules' => [
                    // your rules go here
                ],
                'showScriptName' => false, // Disable index.php
            ],`    I hope this answer your question somehow.

Comment: Please show the result of `Yii::$app->getHomeUrl();` and `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;` and the page browser Url

Comment: `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl` throws void and `Yii::$app->getHomeUrl()` throws /, but that doesn't explain why a simple `href="favicon.ico"` or `href="/favicon.ico"` doesn't work. Page browser Url: [link](http://www.llisoftlab.com) Thanks @scaisEdge.

Comment: This is the problem. the two function  must return the correct  url for get the favicon.ico. If these don't return the right part of the url you can't build the url for get the favicon resource. These functionmust return a valid URL

Answer (score 0):

instead of using :

> Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;

try using :

> Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@frontend/assets/dist')

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Define common parameter in (**`common/config/params.php`**) as below:

```
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,    
    'commonPath' => '/<your_project_name>/common',
];
```

**Step 2 :** Use defined `commonPath` to display favicon icon as follows:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= Yii::$app->params['commonPath']; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Note: Place your `favicon.ico` in `common/` directory.